# SharpSVN and GetLog

Tags: .net, svn

How do I get a list of commits from for SVN path using SharpSvn? I tried something like this:

```
Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> list;
Client.GetLog("svn://1.2.3.4/my/path", new SvnLogArgs(new SvnRevisionRange(new SvnRevision(fromTime), new SvnRevision(SvnRevisionType.Head))), out list);
```

But it doesn't work - it throws ArgumentException ("This argument is not a valid path. A Uri was specified Parameter name: targetPath"). Please note that I do not want to have working copy - everything should be in memory if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should have been:

```
Client.GetLog(new Uri("svn://1.2.3.4/my/path"), new SvnLogArgs(new SvnRevisionRange(new SvnRevision(fromTime), new SvnRevision(SvnRevisionType.Head))), out list);
```

IMO not a very wise interface design, but so be it.